# How to pass ChoiceField choices to formset?

Tags: python-3.x, django-forms, django-views, django-2.2

The name works fine, but I can figure out how to pass the list of choices in the same way.  The fields for those come up blank.  In debugging, the choices appear properly set up.

**forms.py**

```
class MatchSheets(forms.Form):
    """ Match sheets """
    name = forms.CharField()
    propertyuser = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(), required=False)


SheetSet = formset_factory(
    MatchSheets,
    extra=0
)
```

**views.py**

```
    sheets = PropSheetNames.objects.filter(owner=request.user,
                                           sponsoruser=sponsoru_id)
    props = SponsorsUsers.objects.filter(owner=request.user,
                                           id=sponsoru_id).all()

    initial_set = []
    choiceset = (((prop.id), (prop.alias)) for prop in props[0].properties_user.all())

    for sh in sheets:
        initial_set.append(
            {'name': sh.name,
             'propertyuser.choices': choiceset}
        )

    form = SheetSet(request.POST or None, initial=initial_set)
```

I know someone will point out this could be done better with a `modelformset_factory` for the whole thing, or `modelselect` for the `propertyuser`, but I ran into issues with both, and just doing it manually gave me more flexibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this was wrong (corrected):

```
choiceset = [((prop.id), (prop.alias)) for prop in props[0].properties_user.all()]
```

Then added this below `form=`

```
for f in form:
        f.fields['propertyuser'].choices = choiceset
```

Was able to take it further, defaulting the choices to the value of the name field as well:

```
    initial_set = []
    nameset = [prop.alias for prop in props[0].properties_user.all()]
    choiceset = [((prop.alias), (prop.alias)) for prop in props[0].properties_user.all()]
    choiceset.append(('', '----'))
```

and then

```
    for f in form:
        f.fields['propertyuser'].choices = choiceset
        if f.initial['name'] is not None and f.initial['name'] in nameset:
            f.fields['propertyuser'].initial = f.initial['name']
```

Now the user just needs to handle the mismatched pairs, and done.  These were the reasons I was pushed out of using Model options, at least at my ability level.